# How do I increase the request limit in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to upload some files larger than the ~30Mb limit in my .net core web api.  I've tried following all the advice I've found, all listed below.  No matter what I've tried I get back a 404.13 error "Request that exceeds the request content length".  I'm running in visual studio on windows 10, does anybody know how I can get this working?  I'm guessing things might be different when hosting on IIS but I'm trying to get this working first on my machine.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(o => o.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

This one below returns null when trying to get IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature

```
appBuilder.ServerFeatures.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
```

Adding it to my app.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Adding attributes to my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    //[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
    public IActionResult Document(IList<IFormFile> files)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, it turns out I was supposed to create a Web.config file and put what I had put inside my app.config file into there.